# Skyrim Creation Kit - Call External DLL Method

Tags: c#, modding, skyrim-modding

I've been developing for a few years now but I'm fairly new to creating Skyrim mods. I'm wanting to build a custom DLL and call the methods from scripts in Skyrim. Can I do this and if so, how do I import the DLL and make a call to one of it's methods?

Answer (score 1):

The Creation Kit doesn't support external libraries, which is great from a mod safety perspective.

There has been attempts to extend the editor by hooking the process via a proxy d3d9.dll, resulting in products like the [Skyrim Script Extender](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1507966-wipz-skyrim-script-extender-skse/). You may find that the script language that SKSE exposes is sufficient to do what you want to do, otherwise you may clone their work and inject your own code of interest into the process.

Comment: I'm wanting to create a mod just like Skryim Online. I've downloaded his code which is done in C++ so I assume he makes calls to these methods which were coded through Visual Studio. I may be mistaken. Can I use SKSE to communicate across a network to a server in this way?

Comment: I didn't find a way using SKSE to communicate to a server. Still looking for answers online and emailing other developers, but no one so far has answered my question. Does anyone have any ideas?